# 2D array printing C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to print a 2D array, I tried using the following code, but it's only printing the first row of the array, why is it doing that and not printing the whole array in one line?

```
for (int x = 0, y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (; x < 3; x++)
        Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[x, y]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, we just answered the question identically four times.  Hilarious.  I'll delete mine, it really adds nothing.  But, I got an upvote.  So tempting to leave it . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[x, y]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Column based printing.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[x, y]);
    Console.Write("\n"); //added for better formatting
}
```

or

If you don't care about formatting,

```
foreach(var arrEle in arr)
   Console.Write(arrEle+" ");
```

The problem , with your code is that you aren't initializing `x` for every `y`. That is the reason, we have to declare/initialize in inner for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is only set to 0 once at the start of the outer loop, so in the second two iterations of the outer loop, `x=3` and the inner loop test fails.  Try this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[x, y]);
}
```

Comment: `x < 3` as well as `y < 3` looks supicious. `arr.GetLength(0)`, IMHO, should be used

Comment: @DmitryBychenko agreed, that would generalize it.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined x=0 in the outer loop. This means once the inner loop has ran once x will always be 3

Try:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[x, y]);
}
```

Comment: Think you've got a typo there - y is never declared

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple *foreach* loop:

```
foreach (var item in arr)
  Console.Write("{0}, ", item);
```

*foreach* loop will do with *multidimensional* arrays as well.

Comment: The thing is we don't know if he wants all the array or first square 3*3. Isn't it?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: The question states "I want to print a 2D array" and "...printing the whole array in one line", no *square*, *fragment* or the like is mentioned.